# Can samba be run as non-root user?

Tags: permissions, samba

I've set up a service to run samba as non-root user, where the config file for the daemon and the service are on my home directory (on the proper subdirectories). But I keep getting *samba starts and samba stops* and the process exists without any information. (Both on systemctl or journalctl).

Can samba be run as a service and non-root user?

Comment: I've read your question and the accepted answer ( which I'm not challenging ) but I'm confused. You are trying to run smbd.service as a non-root user? Why would you want to do that? Or, is the question can a non-root user create a samba share? If this is the case the answer is yes. It's called a `samba usershare` and it allows any user the ability to share any folder he owns. You can create it from Nautilus graphically or via the command line.

Comment: @Morbius1 Thanks. Normally i try to avoid to run any program with root privileges, and in this case it's not possible. If you do it using nautilus (which I'm not trying to cause this is a test for running on a server afterwards) I think the root password is required. I've just been able to run it after 2 days (the next error was I use VPNs on all my devices..)

Comment: A nautilus share does not require root permissions. That is the whole point of it. And samba isn't a program.

Comment: I'm not interested in nautilus @Morbius1, but also then this should be wrong: "Samba listens to ports below 1024 (135, 445 namely), and convention requires that only root can bind ports below 1024."

Comment: `net usershare add TestShare $HOME/Test "My Test" Everyone:F guest_ok=y && chmod 777 $HOME/Test`I just created a samba usershare in a terminal on an Debian server. It's share definition is in /var/lib/samba/usershares. The ability to do that is limited to users who are members of the sambashare group. No Nautilus. No sudo.

Comment: @Morbius1 yes that's cool and I didn't know about it. But that's rather different from a service and I'll go crazy learning so many things to just launch a share =(. You could post a complete answer for other users.

Comment: That goes back to my original question. This is all possible because samba makes it possible. I'm not taking over ownership of the samba process. I don't want to take over the samba process - as an ordinary user. I don't understand why you want to remove the relative security of root controlling the overall samba process but if that is what you want to do it's best I move on.

Comment: @Morbius1 I'm learning and probably you don't understand just because I may be doing something wrong, but it's my best thought so far. I'm trying to share a folder over a LAN, where guests can only read, and ubuntu users can also write, and I thought initializing a process with non root privileges would be good idea. Many sites tell some processes should be done using root, so idk. For this purpose I thought on using systemd, as this is the main/newest/coolest process manager. Still I couldn't get around using `systemd --user` command.

Comment: @Morbius1 I know you follow more or less the command nautilus is executing, but doing stuff with systemd/smbd and `net` seems to be quite a different thing seen from my newbie hill.

Comment: Ask another question concerning how to have a guest read only + credentialed user write share. Do not include any desire to create some strange non-root instance of the samba service since that that makes no sense. Doing so will only result in a response similar to what vidarlo gave you below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Samba listens to ports below 1024 (135, 445 namely), and convention requires that only root can bind ports below 1024.

However, Linux has a capability interface that can be used to allow services to bind to ports that are below 1024 without root:

```bsh
sudo /sbin/setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=ep' /usr/sbin/smbd
```

Comment: wish i was that clever. thanks a lot. Would you then place all files in the root (system wide) directories?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a misunderstanding. The root user and root directory have nothing to do with eachother. And Samba supports file permissions and users. I think it's better that you describe what you want to achieve, as I believe this is a [X-Y question](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: if i put the service on a user folder, then it will only run with `systemd --user` and hence it won't work for samba, then the configuration file for systemd has to be on the root user folder, basically `/etc/systemd/...`. Is this wrong?

Comment: I believe that's correct, yes. I'm not an expert on systemd tho...

Comment: nvm, even if this is wrong it's probably a better starting point, and i'm only learning, not planning to share even on a WLAN

Comment: "convention requires", yes, [but convention can be overridden](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/allowing-a-user-to-let-listen-to-a-port-below-1024), although it can lead to security issues if Samba is configured to listen to any ports that are designed to be trusted (e.g. SSH and stealing passwords)

Comment: The systemd way to do it would be to  set AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE in the unit file. That way samba only runs with privileges when it's started as a unit, with the configuration in the unit file.